# Rails geocoder gem show results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I'm using the `geocoder gem` in order to set the `longitude` and `latitude` from the address:

```
 class Ub < ApplicationRecord

  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.full_address.present? }

  def full_address
    [street, city, state, zip_code, country].join(",")
  end
end
```

end search:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      location_info = request.location
      @ubs = Ub.near([location_info.latitude, location_info.longitude], 5, :order => :distance)
    else
      @ubs = []
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information on what the latitude/longitude values of your `items` are, it's tough to say for sure, but what jumps out at me from your query is this:

> WHERE (items.latitude BETWEEN -0.07236589155542399 AND 0.07236589155542399 AND items.longitude BETWEEN -0.07236589155542399 AND 0.07236589155542399)

Those upper and lower limits on latitude/longitude represent a small area off the western coast of Africa, so I'm not surprised that none of your `items` are located there.

What values are being returned by `location_info = request.location`? Also, did you see this section from [the documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#request-geocoding-by-ip-address)?

> Note that these methods will usually return nil in your test and development environments because things like "localhost" and "0.0.0.0" are not an Internet IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brian. To answer your questions respectively, values of a couple of items are: `Latitude: 39.6471643, Longitude: -75.6857385`. The `location_info = request.location` is suppose to return the current location of the user according to the ip. Also just a heads up, I used `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` to start the server. My questions are, why isn't it retuning any results at all?? and how can I test this to see if it works??

Comment: I imagine if you replace `location_info = request.location` with `location_info = [39.6471643, -75.6857385]` you'd see some results. You're not seeing any results because you're asking for items that are within five miles of latitude 0, longitude 0, which is in the ocean off the coast of Africa.